# Attach file option is not available for Discussion Board list items in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I could not find any option to attach a file with 'Discussion Board' list item in SharePoint 2013. I have confirmed from Advanced Settings of this list that 'Attachments to list items' option is enabled.

[image: Discussion Board List Item]

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in SP2013 and you cannot add attachment to the item the same way as in 2010. In SP2013 you add an attachment directly to Body field using option in Ribbon (Insert | Upload file).

When uploading a file, by default, files will be stored in SiteAssets library, however you can choose different one if you want.